# Can a Geotools/JTS multipolygon geometry list contain other multipolygons

Tags: geotools, jts

A Geotools/JTS MultiPolygon contains a list of geometries.

Do those geometries have to be Polygons, or could one of them be another MultiPolygon (or even something else)?

Same question also arises for MultiPoints and MultiLineStrings.

thx
g

Answer (score 0):

Possibly but it may cause unexpected problems down the line. It would be better to either "promote" your `Polygon`s to `MultiPolygon`s or make the `List` hold `Geometry`s (or possibly their common interface `Polygonal`).

If you mix geometry types in a `List` you will have problems writing them to most `DataStore`s which expect a consistent data type.